# Block creating a file in a particular folder programatically

Tags: c#, .net, windows, shell, desktop-application

I am working on a Windows Desktop Application using C#. In it I want to implement a certain function such that the user can create a file only inside a folder in the root folder.

Suppose if my root folder is A and there are A1,A2,A3 folders inside it a user can create a file in any of the folder A1,A2,A3. But he should not be allowed to create a file directly inside A.

So in short I want to block file creation in only one particular folder. Is there any way to implement this? Is it possible using shell scripting?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to prohibit creating files in this particular folder from inside the application only? Or blocking it system-wide? Also what have you tried already?

Comment: Have you tried exploiting `FileSystemWatcher`?

Comment: @mnme : from inside the application.Bcoz the folder A ie the root folder is created from the application programatically.

Comment: @Yahya : yes. I did. The File watcher doesnt prevent a user from creating one. It just watches what all happens inside a particular folder.

Comment: @user3222297 So how do you let the user create files? Do they choose the path via a dialog?

Comment: @mnme: Yes..The user can create files. no..not choosing the path ..

Comment: @user3222297 then tell me please how, I can't help you prevent the user creating files when I don't know how they are selected and created. A little snipopet of your source would be greatly appreciated or just a description of your workflow (like: user sets file path in textbox -> parse path and create file).

Comment: @mnme : Once the user installs my application a folder say A is created in the c drive of the local. Inside this folder the user can create as many folder he needs.But he shouldnt be able to create a file.Do you need the codes of how I create the root (A) folder?

Comment: @user3222297 No I see now what you are trying to do. Unfortunately there's no way to prevent this ultimately, there will always be a workaround on the user side. I think you should try to change this and don't rely on the user (or Windows, which also creates files like Thumbs.db) not putting files in the folder.

Comment: This is what permissions are for.

Comment: @HarryJohnston : I need to set the permission programmatically. Can you please tell me how to implement that?

Comment: I believe you'd want to use the `System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity` class.  If you run into trouble, I suggest you post another question specifically asking how to set permissions on a directory in C#.  (I'd have thought this would have already been asked and answered, but if so I can't find it!)

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper around .net method you use to create the file. Then implement a black-list (or a white-list) which you could use to specify what folders to block (or in case of while-list allow).

At start up, load the list into a `List<string>` and use it within the wrapper to determine whether or not to perform the operation

For example, if you use `File.Create` to create the file; your wrapper may look like the following

```
public void CreateFile(string folderName, string fileName, IList<string> whiteList)
{
  // can I create the file in this folder ????
  if (!whiteList.Any(f => f.Equals(folderName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
  {
   // No apparently not... I should now throw an exception
  }

  // create the file
  File.Create(string.Format("{0}/{1}", folderName, fileName)).Dispose();

}
```

Now when ever you want to create a file in your application, use `CreateFile` instead of `File.Create`

Comment: Hi..Thanks for the code. But apparently this is not what I am looking for. I am not using a file.Create method in this. The user should not create a file in windows . In windows we can create a folder by right clicking and clicking New. I should block the creation of file in root folder that way!

Comment: Hi, based on previous comments, I thought you wanted to control the action from within the application. So if you want to restrict the user from creating files in parent, why not use standard windows permission??? - Cheers

Comment: By using standard windows permission can we restrict the user to create files only in a particular folder only?sorry but i don't have much idea on how to specify windows permission.

Comment: Only the root folder is being created programmatically. Once the user installs my application a folder say A is created in the c drive of the local. Rest the files and folders inside the root can be created by the user without running the app. simply by right clicking

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you are trying to do. I assume an administrator will install the application. Following link should help you to understand what permission you should use. https://www.uwec.edu/Help/drives/permissions.htm. What your looking for is at the bottom of the article (special permission). But reading the whole article will prime your knowledge on NTFS permission

Answer (score 0):

At time of Folder Creation,

You can check Parent Folder Name...

Ex: Directory.GetParent("A\A1");
This will give you folder Name A as DirectoryInfo Name.

You can compare your RootFolderName with GetParent Name and restrict creation from application.

Thanks

Comment: As I have said the file creation is not being done programmatically.the user can right click and click new and create a file in the local.

Comment: And again .I need to prevent file creation not folder creation. I need to ensure that a file is not being created inside root folder and at the same time the user must be able to create folders inside the root folder.